# Failed to map the path 'MyAppName/App_GlobalResources' when running ASP.NET page in IIS

Tags: iis, .net-3.5

I get the error "Failed to map the path 'MyAppName/App_GlobalResources'", where MyAppName is the name registered in IIS. I ran aspnet_regiis -i,and also removed .NET 3.5 and reinstalled it since the IIS had been installed later. However, the moment i run a aspx page, this is the error i get.

What does this error really mean , and what is the way out of it ?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it as advised in similar problems faced by others

"In RegEdit, give ASPNET account full access to:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{70B51430-B6CA-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750}"

Comment: Just give permissions to MyMachine\IIS_IUSRS to read the folder having the website files. This permission comes by default if you put the files in C:\inetpub\wwroot, but if you place the files elsewhere, you need to add the permissions explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7 then right click on  visual studio and run as administrator. It will solve your problem.